# Почему письмо приходящее на почту не переводится в блоке {% trans %} django?

Tags: django

Текст письма приходящего на почту:

```
{% load i18n %}

<html>
<title>Company - {% trans 'Activation by email' %}</title>
<body>
    <p>{% trans 'Hello' %}, {{ user }}</p>
    <p>{% trans 'Your  account in Company name has been successfully created. Please click link below to activate your account.'%}</p>
    <p><a href="{{ activate_url }}">{% trans 'Activate your account' %}</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Таск с отправкой письма:

```
def mail_send(scheme, host, user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(pk=user_id)
    text_content = 'Account Activation Email'
    subject = 'Email Activation'
    template_name = "activation.html"
    from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
    recipients = [user.email]
    # receive url with encoded data
    context = encoder(scheme, host, user)

    html_content = render_to_string(template_name, context)
    email = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, recipients)
    email.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    mail_sent = email.send()

    return mail_sent
```

Comment: Потому что информация о нужном языке берётся из текущего request, а у вас тут нету request

Comment: @andreymal, Да это я выяснил, но проблема в решении этого вопроса. А sheme в данном случае не содержит информацию request? Можете написать свое решение или мнение в ответ